# @ConditionalOnProperty doesn't work as its havingValue property

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans, spring-annotations, conditional-on-property

```yaml
// application.yml
board:
  qtalk:
    expiration: false
```

```kotlin
// ScheduleService.kt
@Service
class ScheduleService {

    @Bean("executeAdopt")
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["board.qtalk.expiration"], havingValue = "true")
    fun run() {
        println("scheduler")
    }

}
```

As `application.yml` the value of board.qtalk.expiration is `false`.
Also I set the scheduler method to run when the value is `true`.
According to this, the method shoudn't run but when I run the application, the scheduler method runs.

So I debug to check the value of `board.qtalk.expiration`.

```kotlin
@Autowired
lateinit var environment: Environment

@Bean("executeAdopt")
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["board.qtalk.expiration"], havingValue = "true")
fun run() {
    println("scheduler")
    println("environment property: ${environment.getProperty("board.qtalk.expiration")}")
}
```

```
// console
scheduler
environment property: false
```

But the method still run and print the value `false` even the property condition of `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation is `true`.

What's the reason and what I missed with it?